# Sum up an attribute from children components

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have two components `supplies` and `supply`
I do a `v-for` inside the `supplies` so I create many of the `supply` children

```js
<supply
  v-for="supply in supplies"
  :supply="supply"
  :key="supply.id"
 ></supply>
```

And inside the supply I can choose a `quantity` and multiply it by the `supply.price` to get the `total`

```js
computed: {
  total () {
    return this.supply.price * this.quantity
  }
}
```

What I want to know is how can I sum all the `total` from all the `supply` component

Thank you in advance

Comment: You would need to setup a watcher to watch the `quantity` change on it and push the value of the `total()` back up to the parent where it's listening, and then update a variable in the parent that controls this

Comment: I have watched the the total and emit and event as you referred and changed the `total` data on the `supplies` but it kept add the amount each time I change the quantity (eg: from 1 to 2, and then from 2 to 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Components can communicate to parents via events. Watch the 'total' computed property and emit an event with that value (E.G. $emit('total-changed', total)). Then listen for that event and update the state (data) on the 'supplies' parent. I've generalized a lot, but there are many ways to do this. It would depend on your specific preference/needs.

Comment: At first I did exactly as you mentioned, but when changing the quantity for a specific `supply` component it doesn't re-apply the total but instead it appends to it,
so if I keep only changing the quantity in one `supply` it keeps just adding and adding

Comment: @AdamKeen Wrap the value in `Number(value)` so that an addition is performed and not concatenated.

Comment: if you pass the supply.id in your event then you can map that total back to your parent's 'supply' object. then make your parent's total be a sum of all the supply.total's, for example.

Comment: That's dont what I meant
let say the price of a supply equal 1500
so when I change the quantity to 1 the `supplies` total will be 1500
but when I change the quantity again from 1 to 2 the `supplies` total will not be 3000 as It should but It will be `4500` (old)1500 + (new)3000

Comment: Replace the value instead of adding:
$emit('total', { supplyId: 1, total: 1500 }). then 
suppliesParent.onTotal(event) { this.supplies.find(s => { return s.id == event.supplyId }).total = event.total }

Comment: @AndrewCastellano This is interesting and it seems to be working from the first read, but do you think that's so much logic just to get the total or it's normal

Comment: That's a good question, but you'd have to wait for an answer from a better vue developer :)

Comment: @AndrewCastellano yes I hope I get some other feedback but for now your answer solved my problem, thank you )